# My google maps V3 is not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to convert this code from APIv2 to v3 but I can't get it to work. Would someone help me find the error?

The maps do not start and I don't understand why. I have been using this same code but with the code for v2 API in the past without issues but right now I can´t see were the problem is.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
{if $listing.location_is_set}
var zoom = 15;
{else}
var zoom = 7;
{/if}
{literal}
        var latitude = {/literal}{$geoData.latitude}{literal};
        var longitude = {/literal}{$geoData.longitude}{literal};

$(document).ready(function(){

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude), zoom);
        map.addControl(new google.maps.SmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new google.maps.MapTypeControl());
        map.addControl(new google.maps.ScaleControl());
        map.addControl(new google.maps.OverviewMapControl());
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(point, {draggable: true});
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragstart", function() {
                    map.closeInfoWindow();
                  });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
            $("#m_lat").val(marker.getLatLng().lat());
            $("#m_lon").val(marker.getLatLng().lng());
          });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(overlay,  
 latlng) {
            marker.setLatLng(latlng);
            $("#m_lat").val(marker.getLatLng().lat());
            $("#m_lon").val(marker.getLatLng().lng());
        });


        map.addOverlay(marker);
    }
);

</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: That is not Google Maps Javascript API v3 code.  You have to remove _all_ the v2 syntax (.addOverlay, .setLatLng, .getLatLng, ...).  See the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3)

Answer (score 1):

This is the code in your template (smarty-powered ?).

As a first step, rather look at the generated javascript (view source from browser)

It will avoid to focus on JS if it's a template-related problem.

Comment: Thank You Pierre! Yes it is smarty-powered.  The last part of the code 
the overlay part looks OK for you? is it correct for Apiv3?